# Apply diff fonts for diff types of Text content in UILabel - ios

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to apply diff types of fonts on name of person example " Gopinath Puppala 123”. this is dynamic person name coming from service.

Here in name() any where any numbers of symbols might come. So i should apply system font only to see exactly it.

for Gopinath Puppala i should apply custom font. This should not impact on symbols. This custom font do not have symbols inside font.

Please suggest solution how to apply one font for symbols, one font for alphabets etc..

Thanks In Advance
Gopinath PUPPALA

Comment: Try using `NSAttributedString`, `UILabel` supports it.

Comment: are you getting sybols and names saperatly ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Extract `symbolString` and `nameString` separately and use in the code below

```
let labelString = NSMutableAttributedString()
let symbolString = NSAttributedString(string: symbolString : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)])
labelString.append(symbolString)
let nameString = NSAttributedString(string: nameString "CustomFontName", size: 11.0)])
labelString.append(nameString)

labelObject.attributedText = labelString
```